# scrollTop() and slide-like animation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a page act as a slideshow, with each section appearing as a slide. The HTML is 4 section elements, each IDed as about, about2, etc. I'm using jQuery to make them take the window height when loading. On scroll down, I activated that function, that goes from one slide to the other.

It works well on the first slide, but is then stuck on it. If I reload the page and reloads at that position, it works until the next slide, where it gets stuck again.

Looking at the value, I can see that the conditions are there to activate the next animation (for example, animate to #about3), but it refuses to move (always animate to #about2 when scrolling).

Am I doing something wrong here?

```
function scrollDown(){
    $height = window.innerHeight;
    $scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    console.log($scroll+' and '+$height);
    if ( $scroll > 0 && $scroll < $height) {
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $("#about2").offset().top}, 1000);    
    } else if ($scroll > $height && $scroll < 2*$height) {
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $("#about3").offset().top}, 1000);    
    } else if ($scroll > 2*$height && $scroll < 3*$height) {
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $("#about4").offset().top}, 1000);    
    }
}
```

Here is a JSfiddle with my code: https://jsfiddle.net/9b8s6pna/

Comment: jsfiddle would be helpful

Comment: Good idea @phenxd, I just added it

Comment: why don't you use fullpage.js plugin? it is easy to setup, cross-browser, and responsive to different devices. You can find it here     http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/#firstPage

Comment: works like a charm! I guess I should look into plugins first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close but just missing just one thing. It didn't seem like it was making it to the next section because of the number of times the scrollDown function was being called. You created an event to fire every time a scroll takes place and then told the window to do some more scrolling which would fire more scroll events creating a long chain. Essentially, a whole bunch of animation requests were being queued up. Eventually, if you let the page sit long enough, it would scroll down to the about3 section.

I added a boolean to keep track of when the window is scrolling and I added it to your logic checks. This should help prevent the excessive animation calls :] When the conditions are met for the window to scroll to a specific section, the boolean 'isScrolling' is set to true. When the animation is complete, that boolean is then reset back to false and another scrolling animation can take place.

```
var isScrolling = false;

function scrollDown(){
    $height = window.innerHeight;
    $scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    console.log($scroll+' and '+$height);
    if ( $scroll > 0 && $scroll < $height && isScrolling === false) {
            console.log('about1');
            isScrolling = true;
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("#about2").offset().top
            }, 1000, function(){ isScrolling = false; }
        );    
    } else if ($scroll > $height && $scroll < $height * 2 && isScrolling === false) {
            console.log('about2');
            isScrolling = true;
            $('html, body').animate({
                            scrollTop: $("#about3").offset().top
                            }, 1000, 
            function(){ isScrolling = false; }
         );    
    } else if ($scroll > 2*$height && $scroll < $height * 3 && isScrolling === false) {
            console.log('about3');
            isScrolling = true;
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("#about4").offset().top
                }, 1000,
                function(){ isScrolling = false; }
        );    
    }
}
```

Also, note, I had to add one minor tweak to the CSS to set the margin on the body to 0. This was causing a problem in the comparisons and would make the page think it was scrolled further down than it actually was, thereby initiating a scroll to the next section on down throughout the whole page. By scrolling once, it would create a chain reaction that would scroll through the whole site in one go. To see this in action, just remove the margin: 0; on the body tag on this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sm1215/x1ufkb18/1/).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation! Due to time constraint I went with the Fullpage plugin but I understand the way scroll() work way better now. I'll keep that in mind next time I have to write a similar function.